# SSRS - Clicking View Report Button Returns Focus to Parameter with Value Unset

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I'm trying to run a `Report` in `SSRS 2012`, it's set up, and all the code runs fine in `SSMS`.  But in `SSRS` I get the following:

1. Fill in all the parameters

[image: Report Header with all Parameters selected]

2. Press View Report
3. The following appears

[image: Report Header after View Report]
As you can see, the ToDate Parameter field is asking for a value again.
The following is the code for the parameters:

**Fiscal Parameter**

```
SELECT  
    FiscalPeriodId
    ,FiscalPeriodName + ' - ' + [Status] + ' ' + Convert(varchar(15),ENDDate, 101) AS FiscalPeriodName   
    ,FiscalPeriodId AS OrderId
FROM fin.FiscalPeriod 
WHERE Status = 'Closed'  
    AND GeneralLedgerGroupId = @Location

UNION 

SELECT  
    FiscalPeriodId
    ,'Current'
    ,9999999 AS OrderId
FROM fin.FiscalPeriod
WHERE Status IS NULL 
    AND GeneralLedgerGroupId = @Location

UNION

SELECT 
    0 AS FiscalPeriodId
    ,'AS of Specified Date' AS FiscalPeriodName
    ,10000000 AS OrderId
ORDER by OrderId DESC
```

**Date Parameter**

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN fp.ENDDate IS NULL 
            THEN GETDATE()
            ELSE fp.ENDDate
        END AS ToDate
FROM fin.FiscalPeriod fp
WHERE FiscalPeriodID = @FP 

UNION

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @FP IS NULL 
            THEN GETDATE()
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS ToDate
ORDER BY ToDate DESC
```

I've searched the web and found one question on `Stackoverflow` which seemed to be the same question, but there was no answer to it `(2012)`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I've read somewhere to fix this issue, you need to insert your results into a temp table for your default parameter.  I have not tried this myself but figured you have nothing to lose.

Comment: Does the To Date parameter have available values set? To take a guess, it appears that pressing the View Report button is triggering cascading parameters which sets the To Date to the end date of the Fiscal Period and that isn't an available value for the To Date parameter, causing this parameter to ask you for a valid value.

Comment: I seemed to be getting a conflict with a default value. I wound up adding another parameter. More complex, but it passed code review. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.